# sklearn PoissonRegressor giving all coefficients zero

Tags: generalized-linear-model, scikit-learn, poisson-regression, statsmodels

I'm doing a random exercise of comparing statsmodels and sklearn regression tools, specifically Poisson Regression (unregularised GLM).

I am trying different libraries on the Insurance dataset from statsmodels

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('Insurance', package='MASS').data
```

It has categorical columns District, Group, Age and a continuous feature Holders.
The following two give identical reasonable results:

```
# Fit Poisson regression using formula interface
formula = "Claims ~ C(District, Treatment(1)) + C(Group, Treatment('<1l')) + C(Age, Treatment('<25')) + Holders"
model_smf = smf.poisson(formula=formula, data=data).fit()
print(model_smf.summary())
```

and

```
formula = "Claims ~ C(District, Treatment(1)) + C(Group, Treatment('<1l')) + C(Age, Treatment('<25')) + Holders"
model_poisson = sm.GLM.from_formula(formula, data=data, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
print(model_poisson.summary())
```

**The issues arises now:**

Now I try in sklearn, and need to onehot encode the categorical columns:

```
# one-hot encode the categorical columns, and drop the baseline column

ohe_district = pd.get_dummies(data["District"], prefix="District").drop("District_1", axis=1).astype("int")
ohe_group = pd.get_dummies(data["Group"], prefix="Group").drop("Group_<1l", axis=1).astype("int")
ohe_age = pd.get_dummies(data["Age"], prefix="Age").drop("Age_<25", axis=1).astype("int")

X_train = pd.concat([ohe_district, ohe_group, ohe_age, data["Holders"]], axis=1)
y_train = data["Claims"]

model_sklearn = PoissonRegressor(alpha=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
model_sklearn.intercept_
model_sklearn.coef_
```

The intercept is different to statsmodel regression, all the coefficients are 0, and I got this message when fitting the PoissonRegressor,

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in matmul
  grad[:n_features] = X.T @ grad_pointwise + l2_reg_strength * weights
```

I have been trying to figure out for hours now what I have done wrong.

EDIT: tried with sklearn OneHotEncoder too:

```
# with sklearn OneHotEncoder

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

X_train_ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, drop='first').fit(data[["District", "Age", "Group"]])
X_train_ohe = pd.DataFrame(X_train_ohe.transform(data[["District", "Age", "Group"]]), columns=X_train_ohe.get_feature_names_out())

X_train = pd.concat([X_train_ohe, data[["Holders"]]], axis=1)
y_train = data["Claims"]

model_sklearn = PoissonRegressor(alpha=0).fit(X_train, y_train)

print(model_sklearn.intercept_)
print(model_sklearn.coef_)
```

This has the same problem (same intercept coefficient as with `pd.get_dummies` and all coefficients equal 0, and gives same runtime warning)

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! There are `sklearn` models that apply regularization by default. I believe logistic regression is one such example. Other GLMs might do the same. What does the documentation say?

Comment: Thank you @Dave! The documentation for PoissonRegressor is [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html). You are right, by default there is regularisation but I have overidden with ```alpha = 0```. statsmodels GLM by default doesn't apply any regularisation I believe. I have been able to get the results to match when regressing on some other data with numeric features only.

Comment: If you use [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) instead of `pd.get_dummies`, do you get the same results?

Comment: Hi @rickhg12hs thanks for the suggestion. It still gaves the same issue unfortunately (I have added my implementation in an EDIT on the original post).

Comment: This seems likely to be a bug in sklearn rather than an issue with the Asker's setup: using `solver="newton-cholesky"` I get no warning and nonzero coefficients that match except that different reference categories are used.  Probably best to submit an Issue on their github page.

Comment: does one-hot encoding with more than one categorical predictor, and without any penalization, produce an unidentifiability problem that is making things wonky? (Shouldn't lead to all-zero coeffs though, unless the linear algebra breaks silently )

Comment: @BenBolker Since you probably found your way here bc of me, my experimentation seems to suggest it's specific to using the default solver (lbfgs), where even if I drop one of the one-hot columns the GLM throws an error with no regularization. It seems to behave as expected (including an error on the multicollinear case) with the newton-cholesky solver.

Comment: It would be good for someone to post an issue (although I see that `sklearn` has **1600** open issues ...) this is not the same but at least links to some related issues? https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/24752

Comment: I have now submitted an issue on Github: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/27016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment from @Ben Reiniger simply calling `PoissonRegressor` with `solver='newton-cholesky'` meant that fitting gave the same solution as `statsmodels` Poisson GLM, without any warning.

(Replace `PoissonRegressor(alpha=0)` with `PoissonRegressor(alpha=0, solver='newton-cholesky')`)

[sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html) on the Poisson regressor say that this solver is a good choice "especially with one-hot encoded categorical features with rare categories". It is equivalent to IRLS, which is used by `statsmodels`